# VueJS dynamic tabs

Tags: vue.js, tabs, vuejs2

I need your help with one simple thing. I dont see how to display  content according the current tab.

I'm pretty sure the solution so close, something like `v-if` on content part.

```
<button v-for="tab in tabs"
 v-bind:key="tab"
 v-bind:class="['tab-button', { active: currentTab === tab }]"
 v-on:click="currentTab = tab">
{{ tab }}
</button>

<div v-for="(fruit, fruit) in fruits" :key="fruit">
 <p>{{ fruit.name }}</p>
 <p >{{ fruit.price }}</p>
</div>

<div v-for="(vege, vege) in veges" :key="vege">
 <p>{{ vege.name }}</p>
 <p>{{ vege.price }}</p>
</div>
```

script part

```
currentTab: 'fruits',
tabs: ['fruits', 'veges'],
fruits: [
 {
  name: 'fruit', price: '3$'
 }
],
veges: [
 {
  name: 'vege', price: '1$'
 }
 ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just add `v-if` for each tab content(add wrapper because `v-for` has higher priority over `v-if`, added wrapper):

```
 <button v-for="tab in tabs"
   v-bind:key="tab"
   v-bind:class="['tab-button', { active: currentTab === tab }]"
   v-on:click="currentTab = tab">
   {{ tab }}
 </button>
 <div v-if="currentTab === tabs[0]">
     <div v-for="(fruit, index) in fruits" :key="index">
      <p>{{ fruit.name }}</p>
      <p >{{ fruit.price }}</p>
     </div>
 </div>
 <div v-if="currentTab === tabs[1]">
     <div v-for="(vege, vege) in veges" :key="vege">
      <p>{{ vege.name }}</p>
      <p>{{ vege.price }}</p>
    </div>
 </div>
```

P.S. I recommend to use object instead of array, to use tabs like this `v-if="currentTab === tabs.fruits"`;

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<div v-if="currentTab === 'fruits'" v-for="(fruit, fruit) in fruits" :key="fruit">
 <p>{{ fruit.name }}</p>
 <p >{{ fruit.price }}</p>
</div>

<div v-if="currentTab === 'veges'" v-for="(vege, vege) in veges" :key="vege">
 <p>{{ vege.name }}</p>
 <p>{{ vege.price }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this with `v-if` inside template (if you want to toggle more than one element according to [Vue.js Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html))

```
 <template v-if="currentTab === 'fruits'">
    <div v-for="(fruit, index) in fruits" :key="index">
      <p>{{ fruit.name }}</p>
      <p >{{ fruit.price }}</p>
    </div>
 </template>
 <template v-else>
     <div v-for="(vege, index) in veges" :key="index">
       <p>{{ vege.name }}</p>
       <p>{{ vege.price }}</p>
     </div>
</template>
```